# Could we add the ability to link to a specific answer to a question?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, hyperlinks

Elsewhere in meta I was in a discussion where an answer to a related question was very relevant.   But I currently can't point to that answer, other than to say "the answer by author <here - link to question>"

Not a big deal, but would be nice, and presumably easy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can already do that.

Every answer has a share link. That will take you directly to the answer.

Comment: Dang, so it does!  Thanks!

Comment: Is today your meta day or something Oded?

Comment: Every day is my meta day, @hichris123